# Run bash script at boot?

Tags: arch-linux

Im looking for a way to run a bash script at boot that will simply display information. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test"
echo "info"
exit
```

Comment: there are many phases of linux boot you can hook a script off. I assume you wish to see the results? that usually means you need to run it in your window manager, or at login, not at boot.

Comment: I do wish to see the results. I forgot to mention I do not have a graphical interface, I am on a console only installation of arch.

Comment: what init system are you using? systemd? you should find what you need here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd

Comment: yes I am using systemd. I created a script and activated the script.service however it does not display any of the text in the script.

Comment: [Autostarting – ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Autostarting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to run a script at startup.

- Add it to the `/etc/.rc.local` file
- Add it to `/etc/profile.d/foobar.sh`

Though keep in mind, that the script won't print because there is no terminal for standard out.

An alternative might be to put your text in `/etc/motd` file. You will see the contents printed out every time you SSH in to the machine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is the text displayed at boot on the arch linux live cd used for installing arch? Because that is essentially what I am trying to emulate here. Is it with the /etc/motd method?

Comment: Another option would be creating a crontab entry with `@reboot` as the "time".

Comment: Will the cron job run before the login screen? Also how would I get the text of the script cron runs to display on the screen?

Comment: I have a problem with this, that it runs at login, not at boot. So, if I `ssh` into a server, it immediately runs that script at `/etc/profile.d/foobar.sh` in my terminal. Then, Ctrl + C leaves me in a `-bash-5.1#` terminal, not my normal terminal. This may only be for login or for `root` login, not for actual system startup. FYI

Answer (score 2):

If you put a script in `/etc/profile.d/`, it may run at startup, but only because `root` is active. If you do this, then if you run `su`, you may see that script start running again in your terminal. So, while this will run the script coincidentally at system start, it is not the system start that runs the script, but the activity of `root` that starts it.

If you want a script to run a true system startup, not just user login (including `root` login), then try a service. The advantage is that you can check its status with `systemctl status ...` Creating a service is not hard.

**Tweak, then paste this into your terminal** :

```bash
echo '[Unit]
Description=My amazing startup script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/path/to/myamazingstartup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target' > /etc/systemd/system/myamazingstartup.service

chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/myamazingstartup.service
systemctl enable myamazingstartup.service

# Now, `/opt/path/to/myamazingstartup.sh` will run at every startup. 

# Optional to start now:
systemctl start myamazingstartup

# Check how its running:
systemctl status myamazingstartup
```

- The `WantedBy=multi-user.target` part is mandatory, otherwise the `systemctl enable` will fail. The alternative setting is `graphical.target` and others. You can [read more here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506374/315069).
- `Type=simple` is also mandatory
- Put your own information in:

  - `Description=`
  - `ExecStart=`

Voilà! You have a service that runs your script at startup and even allows you to check its status.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your script to emit messages to the system log, use `logger` instead of `echo`.

```
#!/bin/bash
logger <<HERE
test
info
HERE
#exit  # Not really useful; the script will exit anyway
```